# Converting longitude and latitude to altitude and azimuth

Tags: coordinate-systems

I am interested in a problem where a camera is mounted on the Earth that has a mechanism for altitude and azimuth adjustments. The longitude, latitude and altitude of the camera are known, and the camera is assumed to be level. The input is a longitude, latitude and altitude, and the output needs to be the alt-az coordinates of the camera to point at the specified location on Earth.

My question is that this seems like something that many people would have looked at already, but I think I am missing the proper keywords for a search.  Instead, I'm thinking of it as a change of coordinates problem, or a function $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$.

Could someone point me in the right direction on this problem in terms of keywords or terminology? Ultimately, I am interested in a sort of self-calibration where I don't know much about the levelness of the camera, but that is for later.

Comment: what are alt-az coordinates?  Do you mean celestial coordinates?

Comment: They are the altitude and azimuth coordinates of the camera mechanism.  They would be identical to what a telescope would use, but terrestrially.  That is, all the altitude coordinates would likely be negative because the camera would be looking down to the Earth, instead of up to the stars.

Comment: So the input is _two_ sets of latitude, longitude and altitude, one for the camera and one for the target point? How far is the distance between the camera and the motive you need to be able to handle?

Comment: I'm not sure of the use of the word motive here.  So far this is just a theoretical problem, so I am going to ignore issues like the curvature of the Earth.  For example, if my camera is at the north pole, I know that it can't take a picture of the great pyramid, but it could certainly point in that direction; it is the direction that I am interested in.

Comment: My solution thus far is to assume that the camera is at the north pole at height $h_1$ and its zero azimuth setting is along the prime meridian. Then I used the law of cosines and law of sines to see that in order to point to longitude $\theta$, latitude $x$ and height $h_2$, I move the camera to position alt-az position $(\cos^{-1}(\frac{r+h_2)}{\sqrt{(r+h_1)^2+(r+h_2)^2-2(r+h_1)(r+h_2)\cos(x)}}), \theta)$  If I want to adjust the initial longitude of the camera, I just shift $\theta$. 

From here, I can move elsewhere on the Earth relatively easily.